# How to get selectedItem from ListView from a button click in the listView Item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a list view item which has a button and displays properties on an object. I have the command property set up for the button using the mvvm pattern which fires correctly.

My issues is that when a press the button it does not also get the selected item, I am guessing that it has not fired the selectedItem event.

Is it possible to force this event when the button is pressed?

```
 <Button 
         Height="20"
         Width="20"
         Grid.Column="3"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveClick}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=serverListView, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: Are you using the CommandParameter field in your Command? if not you could pass a reference to the item in the list that the button is sat on

Comment: @Andy Yes I am but this is null, I am assuming because the button does not also fire the selected item event, if I select the item first and then press the button the item is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may :
- set the commandParameter of your command to {Binding}
- Bind the SelectedItem to some Property of your VM
- Set this property to the command parameter in the begining of your command execute method

Comment: Sorry I actually have done this, see above in my edit. But if I have not selected the item first before pressing the button it is null. I think i need to maybe go down the tree and force the selected Item, am not sure?

Comment: Your Binding of CommandParameter seems wrong... you should bind it to {Binding}